# How to create a HashMap in java based on the order of HashSet

Tags: java

I have got a LinkedHashMap , and want to create a **new  LinkedHashMap** based on entries present under HashSet

```
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedHashMapDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       // Currently empty
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> newhashmap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        // old hash map
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> oldhashmap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        // Put elements to the map
        oldhashmap.put("Zara", "zaravalue");
        oldhashmap.put("Mahnaz", "Mahnazvalue");
        oldhashmap.put("Ayan", "Ayanvalue");
        oldhashmap.put("Daisy", "Daisyvalue");
        oldhashmap.put("Qadir", "Qadirvalue");

        HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();

        // add elements to the hash set
        hs.add("Zara");
        hs.add("Ayan");
        hs.add("Qadir");

        Iterator iterator = hs.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            String val = oldhashmap.get(key);
        }
    }
}
```

So that the new newhashmap looks as

```
newhashmap.put("Zara", "Zaravalue");
newhashmap.put("Ayan", "Ayanvalue");
newhashmap.put("Qadir", "Qadirvalue");
newhashmap.put("Mahnaz", "Mahnazvalue");
newhashmap.put("Daisy", "Daisyvalue");
```

please let me know if this possible

Comment: You can't rely on the order of elements in a HashSet or HashMap.

Comment: When your HashSet only contains `Zara, Ayan, Qadir` based on which rule the entries `Mahnaz, Daisy` are added to `newhashmap`?

Comment: @Eran that's why he's using a LinkedHashMap

Comment: @jimmycarr He's also using a `HashSet<String>`.

Comment: Oops, I missed that. Yeah he will need to change that to a LinkedHashSet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `remove()` method if you are willing to remove from the old HashSet

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) iterator.next();
    String val = oldhashmap.remove(key);
    newhashmap.put(key, val);
}
newhashmap.putAll(oldhashmap);
```

You might also want to look at creating a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) with a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) using the order you desire, but this might be a little over-complicated for your example.

Edit: You will also need to change your HashSet to a LinkedHashSet so that you can rely on ordering.

Answer (score 1):

My first approach would look like this:

```
...
LinkedHashMap<String, String> storage = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) iterator.next();
    String val = oldhashmap.get(key);
    if(hs.contains(val){
        newhashmap.put(key, val);
    }else {
        storage.put(key, val);
    }
}
newhashmap.putAll(storage);
...
```

This way you can avoid modifying the old hashmap or iterating through the data twice.